# macro for Hide rows in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, row, hide

I'm kinda new to programming in VBA. I read some stuff on the internet but I couldnt find what I need or couldnt get it working. My problem:

in worksheet 'sheet 1' in cell B6 a value is given for how many years a project will be exploited.

in worksheets 'sheet 2' and 'sheet 3' i made a spreadsheet for 50 years ( year 1 to year 50; row 7 to row 56).

in cell b6 in 'sheet 1' i want to enter a value between 1 and 50. when the value is 49 i want to hide row 56 in 'sheet2' and 'sheet 3'. when the value is 48 i want to hide rows 55:56 in 'sheet2' and 'sheet 3', and so on.
this is what i got so far but i cant get it to work automaticly when i change the value in cell B6:

```
Sub test1()
    If Range("sheet1!B6") = 50 Then
    Rows("52:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("sheet1!B6") = 49 Then
    Rows("55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    If Range("sheet1!B6") = 48 Then
    Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
    End If: End If: End If:
    
    End Sub
```

i hope someone can help me with my problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You almost got it.
You are hiding the rows within the active sheet. which is okay. But a better way would be add where it is.

```
Rows("52:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

becomes

```
activesheet.Rows("52:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

i've had weird things happen without it. As for making it automatic. You need to use the worksheet_change event within the sheet's macro in the VBA editor (not modules, double click the sheet1 to the far left of the editor.) Within that sheet, use the drop down menu just above the editor itself (there should be 2 listboxes). The listbox to the left will have the events you are looking for. After that just throw in the macro. It should look like the below code,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
test1
end Sub
```

That's it. Anytime you change something, it will run the macro test1.

Comment: Note: by weird things, for instance, if activesheet no longer refers to the sheet you think that it does, due to a change in workbook or worksheet context, then it will be hiding some other sheets Rows(52:55) which will make it appear as though it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you're on the right path, Benno!

There are some tips regarding VBA programming that might help you out.

1. Use always explicit references to the sheet you want to interact with. Otherwise, Excel may 'assume' your code applies to the active sheet and eventually you'll see it screws your spreadsheet up.
2. As lionz mentioned, get in touch with the native methods Excel offers. You might use them on most of your tricks.
3. Explicitly declare your variables... they'll show the list of methods each object offers in VBA. It might save your time digging on the internet.

Now, let's have a draft code...

Remember this code must be within the Excel Sheet object, as explained by lionz. It only applies to Sheet 2, is up to you to adapt it to both Sheet 2 and Sheet 3 in the way you prefer.

Hope it helps!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    'We only want to do something if the changed cell is B6, right?
    If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then

        'Checks if it's a number...
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then

            'Let's avoid values out of your bonds, correct?
            If Target.Value > 0 And Target.Value < 51 Then

                'Let's assign the worksheet we'll show / hide rows to one variable and then
                '   use only the reference to the variable itself instead of the sheet name.
                '   It's safer.

                'You can alternatively replace 'sheet 2' by 2 (without quotes) which will represent
                '   the sheet index within the workbook
                Set oSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2")

                'We'll unhide before hide, to ensure we hide the correct ones
                oSheet.Range("A7:A56").EntireRow.Hidden = False

                oSheet.Range("A" & Target.Value + 7 & ":A56").EntireRow.Hidden = True

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```