# Excel VBA to Hide Complete Rows based upon the values cells within Named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to figure out some code to perform the following via VBA.

I have at the moment one named range ("Quarter2"), which will eventually expand to a number of other named ranges, names TBC at the moment but probably "Quarter3" and onwards etc

Each of the names ranges has the same layout, i.e. the same information appears in the same columns as they'll be shown on the same tab, or the same layout but on tabs within the same workbook etc

I need a macro to hide the entire row based on the value of one of two cells:

In column B, if the value is >= 1 then it's to be hidden, and/or
In Column D, if the value is >= $50000.00 then it's to be hidden also

The number of ranges need to be expandable so that needs to be taken into account also.

I've have a look at various snippets of VBA that I've found but I can't get one to work for this situation.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `I've have a look at various snippets of VBA that I've found but I can't get one to work for this situation.` - show please what have you tried

Comment: Take a look at [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576423/macro-for-hide-rows-in-excel-2010) it might help answer this.